# Can't deploy to Scrapinghub

Tags: python, deployment, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

When I try to deploy using `shub deploy`, I got this error:

> Removing intermediate container fccf1ec715e6 Step 10 : RUN sudo -u
>   nobody -E PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE pip install --user
>   --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt  ---> Running in 729e0d414f46 Double requirement given: attrs==16.1.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt
>   (line 51)) (already in attrs==16.0.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt
>   (line 1)), name='attrs')
>
> {"message": "The command '/bin/sh -c sudo -u nobody -E
>   PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE     pip install --user --no-cache-dir
>   -r /app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1", "details": {"message": "The command '/bin/sh -c sudo -u nobody -E
>   PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE     pip install --user --no-cache-dir
>   -r /app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1"}, "error": "build_error"}
>
> {"message": "Internal build error", "status": "error"} Deploy log
>   location:
>   c:\users\dr521f~1.pri\appdata\local\temp\shub_deploy_pvx7dk.log Error:
>   Deploy failed: {"message": "Internal build error", "status": "error"}

This is my `requirements.txt`:

```
attrs==16.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
cffi==1.8.2
click==6.6
cryptography==1.5
cssselect==0.9.2
enum34==1.1.6
fake-useragent==0.1.2
hubstorage==0.23.1
idna==2.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
lxml==3.6.1
parsel==1.0.3
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pycparser==2.14
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pyOpenSSL==16.1.0
pypiwin32==219
queuelib==1.4.2
requests==2.11.1
retrying==1.3.3
ruamel.ordereddict==0.4.9
ruamel.yaml==0.12.13
scrapinghub==1.8.0
Scrapy==1.1.2
scrapy-fake-useragent==0.0.1
service-identity==16.0.0
shub==2.4.0
six==1.10.0
Twisted==16.4.0
typing==3.5.2.2
w3lib==1.15.0
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Why can't I deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [here](http://doc.scrapinghub.com/shub.html)

> Note that this requirements file is an extension of the Scrapy Cloud
>   stack, and therefore should not contain packages that are already part
>   of the stack, such as scrapy.

As you can see in the error:

> Running in 729e0d414f46 Double requirement given: attrs==16.1.0 (from
>   -r /app/requirements.txt (line 51)) (already in attrs==16.0.0 (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 1)), name='attrs')

It says `Double requirement given`.

Use different `requirements.txt` for the whole project and for Scrapinghub. I ended up creating `shub-requirements.txt` which contains this:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
fake-useragent==0.1.2
```